# Could not link static c library with shared lib in android using Cmake

Tags: java, android

I have been trying linking prebuilt static library with shared library using CMake.txt.

Following is my Cmake.txt

```
add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.c )


         # Specifies a path to native header files.
        include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/include/)
        add_library(my_test_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties(my_test_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jni/libmytestlib.a)
        target_link_libraries(native-lib my_test_lib)
```

I have put **libmytestlib.a** in src/main/jni location.

I am calling **addnumbers()** function from **native-lib.c(shared lib)**. 
function has definition in static library.

Every time i built the program it gives me error

```
[2/2] Linking C shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Rajeev\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Rajeev/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Rajeev/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem 
 C:/Users/Rajeev/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=18 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot C:/Users/Rajeev/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-18/arch-x86 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.c.o  ../../../../src/main/jni/libmytestlib.a -lm && cd ."
 C:/Users/Rajeev/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: ../../../../src/main/jni/libmytestlib.a(mytestlib.o): incompatible target

D:\Projects\Android_Projects\YegoMotoDriverBikeLoginPassIntg\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.c:37: error: undefined reference to 'addnumbers'

clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Why it is giving **Incompatible target** error every time.. I have searched through stackoverflow but no solution worked.. Please guide ...

**Edit**

**NOTE - Static library libmytestlib.a is pre-built on LINUX machine**

Comment: You need to compile `libmytestlib.a` with the same compiler (and target architecture) as your Android binary. See [the manual](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems) on cross-compiling. If you tell us _how_ you built `libmytestlib.a` we can show you how to cross-compile it.

Comment: @Botje we have used following command to build libmytestlib.a   `$gcc -m64 -c mytestlib.c -o mytestlib.o
$ ar rvs libmytestlib.a mytestlib.o
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest solution is to delegate the building to CMake:

```
add_library(my_test_lib STATIC src/main/mytestlib/mytestlib.c)
target_link_libraries(native-lib my_test_lib)
```

The Android build system will take care of invoking CMake once per platform.

Assuming you cannot do that, you need to build `libmytestlib.a` separately by hand [for each `ANDROID_ABI` you intend to support](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems). You want at least `armv7a-linux-androideabi` and `aarch64-linux-android`.
For example:

```
mkdir -p src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}
clang -target ${ANDROID_ABI}-android21 -c src/main/mytestlib/mytestlib.c -o src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/mytestlib.o
${ANDROID_ABI}-ar rvs src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmytestlib.a src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/mytestlib.o
```

The corresponding CMake snippet is then:

```
add_library(my_test_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(my_test_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmytestlib.a)
target_link_libraries(native-lib my_test_lib)
```

Comment: thanks, i have build static library for all different architectures `armeabi, arch64-v8a and armeabi-v7a` and it works for corrosponding ndk filters set in build.gradle

Comment: I have put these static lib in JNI folder. Now if i set suppose two abi filters in build.gradle say `'armeabi' , 'arch64-v8a'`. How can i put compatbile two libs in same JNI folder.

Comment: You could split the `jni`directory by platform like I did and have cmake use `jni/$ANDROID_ABI/libmytestlib.a`